# CMake и кроссплатформенный C++ проект

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, mingw, кроссплатформенность

Длительное время я разрабатывал под Ubuntu C++17 проект, построенном на CMake(3.26) и собранном с помощью gcc-8 (всё это в IDE Clion).
Сейчас появилась потребность сделать проект кроссплатформенным, т.е. собирать его в .exe файл для Windows.

В проекте используется **Boost**: **Boost::program_options**, **Boost::asio**, **Boost::log**.

Я пытаюсь сбилдить Boost(1.71) с помощью mingw(MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.4) на Windows, но boost::program_options выдаёт разные ошибки. Хотелось бы Подойти к этому вопросу с умом.

Как добиться моей цели? Mingw/Visual Studio? Какие вообще практики для кроссплатформенности лучше всего использовать? Какие-нибудь пакетные менеджеры (hunter/vcpkg)?

Comment: MinGW vs MSVC - это религиозный вопрос. Мне кажется, первый лучше - потому что опенсурс и одинаковый компилятор (и стандартная библиотека C++) на всех платформах (и я бы взял Clang - он может работать и с тем, и с другим). Пакетный менеджер - хорошая вещь. Для MinGW хорош MSYS2, для MSVC хорош vcpkg. (Последний вроде как умеет и в MinGW тоже, но большого доверия к этому нет - он у них для галочки, а для MSYS2 MinGW - основная и единственная платформа.) Про Hunter первый раз слышу. Из популярного есть еще Conan.

Comment: а где описание ошибок то? На практике "кроссплатформенность" даже в рамках линуксов разная. даже названия станнрартных пакетов цпп разнятся

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev библиотеку я уже сбилдил, ошибка была "libboost_program_options-mgw95-mt-s-x64-1_71.a (mgw95, detected mgw9, set Boost_COMPILER to override)", решил.
Вопрос заключался не в "решите мою проблему", а дайте совет, как правильно вообще подходить к кроссплатформе, какие существуют практики и советы.